How to get milliseconds converted into date time format with deciaml value
I have a table as
create table my_table(created timestamp);
The value which I want to insert is - 1706812200000
But it is in milliseconds. I want to convert it into 2024-04-30 16:48:02.079519 format.
I tried -
INSERT INTO my_table (created) VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP(1706812200000::double precision/1000));
It gave me  2024-02-02 00:00:00
I want something like
2024-04-30 16:50:26.037643

With your timestamp value stored in created column, try this - SELECT to_timestamp(1706812200000 / 1000)::timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS formatted_timestamp; This should give you timestamp in expected date-time format.

Thats is going to be difficult as select extract(epoch from '2024-04-30 16:48:02.079519'::timestamp); is 1714495682.079519 and  1706812200000/1000 is 1706812200. There are no fractional seconds in that value.  Which means you get something like select to_timestamp(1706812200000/1000); 2024-02-01 10:30:00-08, I'm in PDT at the moment.
